# How to hide data parsing code in R Markdown

Tags: r-markdown

I am pretty new in R markdown and while creating a report "I like to hide data parsing code"

I have tried "echo=FALSE", but it does not doing the job in this particular case.

Any help would be much appreciated.

````
**Data Parsing**
```{r echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
SU1 <- read_csv("......./SU.csv")
````

I like to hide the below chunk in the report
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Add `include=F` to the chunk options. It is still evaluated, but it won't provide any output to the viewer (HTML for HTML, doc for doc, etc.).

Comment: Thanks ,In fact i was able to solve it by adding Message= FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.In fact i was able to solve it by adding Message= FALSE.